# How to solve "BUG: scheduling while atomic: swapper /0x00000103/0, CPU#0"? in TSC2007 Driver?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I found tsc2007 driver and modified according to our needs. Our firm is producing its own TI DM365 board. In this board we used TSC2007 and connected PENIRQ pin to GPIO0 of DM365. It is being seen OK on driver. when i touch to touchscreen cursor is moving but at the same time i am getting

```
BUG: scheduling while atomic: swapper /0x00000103/0, CPU#0
```

warning and embedded Linux is being crashed. there are 2 files that i modified and uploaded to http://www.muhendislikhizmeti.com/touchscreen.zip one is with timer the other is not. it is giving this error in any case.

I found a solution on web that i need to use work queue and call with using schedule_work() API. but they are blur for me now. Is anybody have any idea how to solve this problem and can give me some advice where to start to use work queue.

Answer (score 40):

"Scheduling while atomic" indicates that you've tried to sleep somewhere that you shouldn't - like within a spinlock-protected critical section or an interrupt handler.

Common examples of things that can sleep are `mutex_lock()`, `kmalloc(..., GFP_KERNEL)`, `get_user()` and `put_user()`.

Answer (score 14):

Exactly as said in 1st answer, scheduling while atomic happens when the scheduler gets confused and therefore unable to work properly and this because the scheduler tried to perform a "schedule()" in a section that contains a schedulable code inside of a non schedulable one.

For example using sleeps inside of a section protected by a spinlock. Trying to use another lock(semaphores,mutexes..) inside of a spinlock-proteced code may also disturb the scheduler. In addition using spinlocks in user space can drive the scheduler to behave as such. Hope this helps

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else with a similar error - I had this problem because I had a function, called from an atomic context, that used `kzalloc(..., GFP_KERN)` when it should have used `GFP_NOWAIT` or `GFP_ATOMIC`.

This is just one example of a function sleeping when you don't want to, which is something you have to be careful of in kernel programming.

Hope this is useful to somebody else!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the former two answers, in my case it was enough to disable the preemption:

```
preempt_disable();

// Your code with locks and schedule()

preempt_enable();
```

Comment: not accurate enough: as caf said, the locks must not sleep.   only spinlock qualify for that.   mutex lock cannot be used (me not sure?), as when mutex lock starts to wait, the CPU can be scheduled out to other processor (because inside mutex_lock() is a "might_sleep()" function call, which may result in voluntary rescheduling - because cond_resched() is called, even though you have set the preemption flag to off (that may result in another bug?), as voluntary scheduling is done when preemption flag is on?   let's discuss.