# What are the possible causes of "BUG: scheduling while atomic?"

Tags: c++, embedded-linux

There is another process continuously creating files that need processing by this code.
This code constantly scans the file-system for new files that need processing by comparing the contents of the file-system against a sqlite database that contains the processing results - one record for each file. This process is running at `nice -n 19` so as not to interfere with the creation of new files by the other process.
It all works perfectly for a large number (>1k) of files, but then blows up with `BUG: scheduling while atomic`. 
According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537252/how-to-solve-bug-scheduling-while-atomic-swapper-0x00000103-0-cpu0-in-ts)

> "Scheduling while atomic" indicates that you've tried to sleep
>   somewhere that you shouldn't

But the only sleep in the code is like this

```
void doFiles(void) {
    for (...) { // for each file in the file-system
        ... // check database - do processing if needed
    }
    sleep(1);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]) {
    while (true) doFiles();
    return -1;
}
```

The code will hit this sleep after it has checked every file in the file-system against the database. The process needs to be repeated since new files will be added from time to time. There is no multi-threading in this code. Are there other possible causes for "BUG: scheduling while atomic" besides a misplaced sleep?

Edit: additional error output:

```
note: mirlin[1083] exited with preempt_count 1
BUG: scheduling while atomic: mirlin/1083/0x40000002
Modules linked in: g_cdc_ms musb_hdrc nop_usb_xceiv irqk edmak dm365mmap cmemk
Backtrace: 
[<c002a5a0>] (dump_backtrace+0x0/0x110) from [<c028e56c>] (dump_stack+0x18/0x1c)
 r6:c1099460 r5:c04ea000 r4:00000000 r3:20000013
[<c028e554>] (dump_stack+0x0/0x1c) from [<c00337b8>] (__schedule_bug+0x58/0x64)
[<c0033760>] (__schedule_bug+0x0/0x64) from [<c028e864>] (schedule+0x84/0x378)
 r4:c10992c0 r3:00000000
[<c028e7e0>] (schedule+0x0/0x378) from [<c0033a80>] (__cond_resched+0x28/0x38)
[<c0033a58>] (__cond_resched+0x0/0x38) from [<c028ec6c>] (_cond_resched+0x34/0x44)
 r4:00013000 r3:00000001
[<c028ec38>] (_cond_resched+0x0/0x44) from [<c0082f64>] (unmap_vmas+0x570/0x620)
[<c00829f4>] (unmap_vmas+0x0/0x620) from [<c0085c10>] (exit_mmap+0xc0/0x1ec)
[<c0085b50>] (exit_mmap+0x0/0x1ec) from [<c0037610>] (mmput+0x40/0xfc)
 r9:00000001 r8:80000005 r6:c04ea000 r5:00000000 r4:c0427300
[<c00375d0>] (mmput+0x0/0xfc) from [<c003b5e4>] (exit_mm+0x150/0x158)
 r5:c10992c0 r4:c0427300
[<c003b494>] (exit_mm+0x0/0x158) from [<c003cd44>] (do_exit+0x198/0x67c)
 r7:c03120d1 r6:c10992c0 r5:0000000b r4:c10992c0
...
```

Comment: Huh. Is any of your code kernel code, like your own kernel module or anything? As far as I'm aware, all userspace code can `sleep` whenever it wants...

Comment: `BUG: scheduling while atomic` has nothing to do with user-level application code. That's kernel code, so either it's a bug with the kernel distributed with your particular Linux flavor, or with your own custom-configured kernel if you've done that, or with a driver/module that you have involved - standard, third-party, or your own...

Comment: @us2012 No. The kernel is linux-2.6.32.17-psp03.01.01.39 and there is no kernel code in the process identified by the `scheduling while atomic` message.

Comment: The message specifies a userspace process? That seem unlikely. Why don't you show us the full message?

Comment: I did get this kernel from RidgeRun. I suppose I could ask them.

Comment: I didn't save the entire error message last time but I'm trying to reproduce it now to create a core dump file. I'll post the full error message when I get it.

Comment: Added additional error output but it runs continuous so it would probably be too much to post here. Also: let me see if I can reproduce the issue after a fresh checkout with a clean build

Comment: Pretty much that whole group of messages comes from the kernel, not from your application (not entirely sure about the first line, but the rest are definitely kernel messages). Those messages may be triggered by your application, but they still indicate something the kernel did not expect, not necessarily a problem with your application.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This error was caused by a bad build.
A clean build by itself did not help.
A fresh checkout and build was required to resolve this issue.

Comment: This, probably, isn't the actual thing that caused it to appear.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you can sleep() anytime you want to in user code.

Looks like a problem with a driver on your platform.  The driver may not actually call sleep() or schedule(), but often it will make a call of an kernel function which will, in turn, call one of these.

This also looks like it is using memory mapped file I/O on an embedded TI ARM processor.