# Why empty critical section within netfilter hooks, occurs `BUG: scheduling while atomic error`?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, netfilter, mutual-exclusion

I've written this hook:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/netfilter.h>
#include <linux/netfilter_ipv4.h>
#include <linux/skbuff.h>
#include <linux/mutex.h>

static struct nf_hook_ops nfho;
static struct mutex critical_section;

unsigned int hook_func(unsigned int hooknum,
   struct sk_buff **skb,
   const struct net_device *in,
   const struct net_device *out,
   int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff *)) {

  mutex_lock(&critical_section);

  mutex_unlock(&critical_section);

  return NF_ACCEPT;
}

int init_module() {

  nfho.hook = hook_func;
  nfho.hooknum = NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING;
  nfho.pf = PF_INET;
  nfho.priority = NF_IP_PRI_FIRST;

  mutex_init(&critical_section);

  nf_register_hook(&nfho);

  return 0;
}

void cleanup_module() {
  nf_unregister_hook(&nfho);
}
```

init section:

```
  mutex_init(&queue_critical_section);
  mutex_init(&ioctl_critical_section);
```

I have defined static variable:

```
static struct mutex queue_critical_section;
```

As there is no code between `lock` and `unlock` I expect no error, but when I run this module, the kernel produce these errors:

## Error Updated:

```
root@khajavi: # pppd call 80-2
[  519.722190] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
root@khajavi:# [  519.917390] BUG: scheduling while atomic: swapper/0/0/0x10000100
[  519.940933] Modules linked in: ppp_async crc_ccitt ppp_generic slhc netfilter_mutex(P) nls_utf8 isofs udf crc_itu_t bnep    rfcomm bluetooth rfkill vboxsf(O) vboxvideo(O) drm]
[  520.022203] CPU 0 
[  520.023270] Modules linked in: ppp_async crc_ccitt ppp_generic slhc netfilter_mutex(P) nls_utf8 isofs udf crc_itu_t bnep rfcomm bluetooth rfkill vboxsf(O) vboxvideo(O) drm]
[  520.087002] 
[  520.088001] Pid: 0, comm: swapper/0 Tainted: P           O 3.2.51 #3 innotek GmbH VirtualBox/VirtualBox
[  520.130047] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff8102d17d>]  [<ffffffff8102d17d>] native_safe_halt+0x6/0x8
[  520.135010] RSP: 0018:ffffffff81601ee8  EFLAGS: 00000246
[  520.140999] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffffffff810a4cfa RCX: ffffffffffffffbe
[  520.145972] RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000001
[  520.158759] RBP: ffffffff81601ee8 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[  520.163392] R10: 0000000000000400 R11: ffff88003fc13680 R12: 0000000000014040
[  520.172784] R13: ffff88003fc14040 R14: ffffffff81067fd2 R15: ffffffff81601e58
[  520.177767] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff88003fc00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  520.188208] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 000000008005003b
[  520.196486] CR2: 00007fff961a3f40 CR3: 0000000001605000 CR4: 00000000000006f0
[  520.201437] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
[  520.212332] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000ffff0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
[  520.217155] Process swapper/0 (pid: 0, threadinfo ffffffff81600000, task ffffffff8160d020)
[  520.228706] Stack:
[  520.234394]  ffffffff81601ef8
Message from syslogd@khajavi at Dec 22 17:45:46 ...
 kernel:[  520.228706] Stack:
 ffffffff81014857 ffffffff81601f28 ffffffff8100d2a3
[  520.255069]  ffffffffffffffff 0d64eb669fae50fc ffffffff81601f28 0000000000000000
[  520.269238]  ffffffff81601f38 ffffffff81358c39 ffffffff81601f78 ffffffff816acb8a
[  520.274148] Call Trace:
[  520.275573]  [<ffffffff81014857>] default_idle+0x49/0x81
[  520.278985]  [<ffffffff8100d2a3>] cpu_idle+0xbc/0xcf
[  520.291491]  [<ffffffff81358c39>] rest_init+0x6d/0x6f
```

here is the complete syslog error: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6617614/

Comment: yes I have define and initialize it.

Comment: That error message is incomplete.

Comment: @CL. I've updated the error message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a hook from inside the kernel. Sleeping, locking a semaphore (pend) or any blocking operations are not allowed; You are locking the kernel!

If you want synchronization object, you might try to use spin locks.

As [this answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8354577/231388) stated, mutex_lock will trigger scheduler; But the kernel will be puzzled because you are trying to schedule another task, while you are in critical section (the callback itself is big critical section).

Check this thread [Understanding execution context of netfilter hooks](http://www.spinics.net/lists/netfilter-devel/msg09964.html) for similar case.

Comment: If locking with mutex in kernel is not allowed, so why kernel developers created mutex API inside the kernel?

Comment: @Khajavi Mutexes are allowed in some contexts, but not in netfilter hooks.

Answer (score 6):

Even though `mutex_lock()` probably won't sleep in this case, it still *might* sleep.
Since this is called in an atomic context, the error is raised.

Specifically, this is caused by `mutex_lock()` calling `might_sleep()`, which in turn may call `__schedule()`

If you do need to synchronize, use the appropriate calls, eg. spinlocks and rcu.

Answer (score 5):

You see this message if your task scheduled when it holds an synchro, most probably a spinlock.
When you lock a spinlock it increases preempt_count; when the scheduler detests the situation of scheduling with increased preempt_count it prints out the exactly that message:

/*
 * Print scheduling while atomic bug:

```
 */
static noinline void __schedule_bug(struct task_struct *prev)
{
        if (oops_in_progress)
                return;

        printk(KERN_ERR "BUG: scheduling while atomic: %s/%d/0x%08x\n",
                prev->comm, prev->pid, preempt_count());

        debug_show_held_locks(prev);
        print_modules();
        if (irqs_disabled())
                print_irqtrace_events(prev);
        dump_stack();
}
```

So, probably you are holding a lock or you must to unlock some lock.

PS. From the mutex description in Linux documentation:

> - 'struct mutex' semantics are well-defined and are enforced if    CONFIG_DEBUG_MUTEXES is turned on. Semaphores on the other hand have
>     virtually no debugging code or instrumentation. The mutex subsystem
>     checks and enforces the following rules:
>
>   - - only one task can hold the mutex at a time    * - only the
>         owner can unlock the mutex    * - multiple unlocks are not permitted
>   - - recursive locking is not permitted    * - a mutex object must be initialized via the API    * - a mutex object must not be initialized
>         via memset or copying    * - task may not exit with mutex held    * -
>         memory areas where held locks reside must not be freed    * - held
>         mutexes must not be reinitialized    * - mutexes may not be used in
>         hardware or software interrupt    *   contexts such as tasklets and
>         timers

In your design the same mutex could be used several times simultaneously:

1. call 1 -> you code -> mutex_lock
2. scheduler interrupts your code.
3. call 2 -> your code -> mutex_lock (already locked) -> BUG

Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

This is a clearly a execution context problem. To use appropriate locking in kernel code, one needs to be aware in which execution context (`hard_irq` | `bottom_half` | `process_context`) the code gets called.

`mutex_lock` | `mutex_unlock`  are solely for guarding process_context code.

according to http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/iptables/devel/56853

discussion, your function `hook_func` can be called in `sot_irq` or `process_context`.
So, you need to use locking mechanism suitable for guarding between these two context.

I suggest you go through kernel-locking guide (https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/rusty/kernel-locking/). The guide also explains the peculiarities involved when system is SMP (very common) and preemption is on.

for quick test you can use `spin_lock_irqsave` lock in your `hook_func`. `spin_lock_irqsave` is always safe, it disables interrupts on current cpu and spinlock will guarantee atomic operation on SMP system.

Now, word about the crash:

`mutex_lock` | `mutex_unlock` can only be used in process_context code. When your `hook_func` gets called from `soft_irq`, `mutex_lock` causes current process to sleep and in turn invokes scheduler.  Sleeping in kernel code is not allowed in atomic context (here it is `soft_irq`).