# Stopping a Kernel thread using a timer in linux

Tags: linux, timer, kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to stop a kernel thread by calling kthread_stop() inside a function which will be called by timer.When I load this module into the kernel, kthread is starting and stopping after the specified time mentioned in the timer but its giving some error message in the log.

Can someone help me to solve this problem as I am new to kernel thread programming.This is my code

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/timer.h>
#include <linux/kthread.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
struct task_struct *task;
static struct timer_list my_timer;
int thread_function(void *data) {
    printk(KERN_ALERT"IN THREAD FUNCTION");
    while(!kthread_should_stop()){
    schedule();
    }
printk(KERN_ALERT"after schedule\n");
return 1;
}

void my_timer_callback( unsigned long data ){
printk( "my_timer_callback called (%ld).\n", jiffies );
printk(KERN_ALERT"THREAD STOPPED\n");
kthread_stop(task);
}

int init_module( void ){
    int ret;
    printk("Timer module installing\n");

    //my_timer.function, my_timer.data
    setup_timer( &my_timer, my_timer_callback, 0 );

    printk( "Starting timer to fire in 2000ms (%ld)\n", jiffies );
    ret = mod_timer( &my_timer, jiffies + msecs_to_jiffies(2000) );
    if (ret) printk("Error in mod_timer\n");
    printk(KERN_INFO"-------------------- THREAD START------------------------");

    task = kthread_run(thread_function,NULL,"kerneltthread");
    printk(KERN_ALERT"Kernel Thread Name: %s\n",task->comm);

    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module( void ){
    int ret;

    ret = del_timer( &my_timer );
    if (ret) printk("The timer is still in use...\n");

    printk("Timer module uninstalling\n");

    return;
}

 MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

This is the output message in the log

```
Aug  5 16:35:31 brao kernel: Timer module installing
Aug  5 16:35:31 brao kernel: Starting timer to fire in 2000ms (4299209850)
Aug  5 16:35:31 brao kernel: -------------------- THREAD             START------------------------
Aug  5 16:35:31 brao kernel: Kernel Thread Name: kerneltthread
Aug  5 16:35:31 brao kernel: IN THREAD FUNCTION
Aug  5 16:35:33 brao kernel: my_timer_callback called (4299211856).
Aug  5 16:35:33 brao kernel: THREAD STOPPED
Aug  5 16:35:33 brao kernel: BUG: scheduling while atomic: swapper/3/0/0x10000100
Aug  5 16:35:33 brao kernel: after schedule
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537252/how-to-solve-bug-scheduling-while-atomic-swapper-0x00000103-0-cpu0-in-ts

Comment: I'm not sure about the the bug, but something seems wrong in the init_module function. You're adding a timer with an uninitialized expires field and only after that you're setting the expires field. I'd suggest you call init_timer then set expires, function and data and then finally call add_timer. Otherwise there's a bogus timer for a short time, which might be called when you were not expecting it.

Comment: Also a waitqueue would be more appropriate in this case instead of repeatedly calling schedule() while waiting for the timer function to be executed.

Comment: But anway, when the function is_atomic() returns a positive number your thread should not be allowed to sleep/call schedule. You should introduce checks to your thread to find the places where you run in such a context.

Answer (score 1):

**Timer's function** is executed in softirq context, because of that it **shouldn't sleep**. But your `my_timer_callback` calls `kthread_stop` function, which *waits* until kthread is finished, that is sleep.

So, `scheduling while atomic` BUG is arised: function sleeps while it shouldn't do that because of atomic context.

Comment: `kthread_stop` stops thread, but it should be called from the *process* context (as opposite to atomic context). You may use, e.g., `delayed_work` for that.