# What are the reasons for DMA timeouts?

Tags: linux-kernel, dma

I see a timeout happening when trying to allocate a DMA memory region. While I can remove this bug by using GFP_ATOMIC instead of GFP_KERNEL als gfp flags, so that the DMA allocation becomes non-interruptible, I wonder what the reasons for the occurrence of such a timeout? The requested memory region is not known to the system bus? The bus is saturated?

```
[   87.400000] [<c0138eec>] (schedule_bug) from [<c05a0774>] (schedule+0x3c/0x528)
[   87.410000] [<c05a0774>] (__schedule) from [<c05a0d0c>] (schedule+0xac/0xcc)
[   87.410000] [<c05a0d0c>] (schedule) from [<c05a3e20>] (schedule_timeout+0x20/0x2b8)
[   87.420000] [<c05a3e20>] (schedule_timeout) from [<c05a1804>] (wait_for_common+0xf8/0x1a8)
[   87.430000] [<c05a1804>] (wait_for_common) from [<c012c540>] (flush_work+0x174/0x1ac)
[   87.450000] [<c012c540>] (flush_work) from [<c01a0648>] (drain_all_pages+0x108/0x130)
[   87.460000] [<c01a0648>] (drain_all_pages) from [<c01d6d34>] (start_isolate_page_range+0xbc/0x284)
[   87.470000] [<c01d6d34>] (start_isolate_page_range) from [<c01a3310>] (alloc_contig_range+0xdc/0x330)
[   87.480000] [<c01a3310>] (alloc_contig_range) from [<c01d7658>] (cma_alloc+0x170/0x308)
[   87.490000] [<c01d7658>] (cma_alloc) from [<c011142c>] (__alloc_from_contiguous+0x40/0xd8)
[   87.500000] [<c011142c>] (__alloc_from_contiguous) from    [<c0111500>] (cma_allocator_alloc+0x3c/0x44)
[   87.510000] [<c0111500>] (cma_allocator_alloc) from [<c010f86c>] (__dma_alloc+0x1d4/0x2fc)
[   87.520000] [<c010f86c>] (__dma_alloc) from [<c010fa0c>] (arm_dma_alloc+0x3c/0x48)
[   87.530000] [<c010fa0c>] (arm_dma_alloc) from [<c03ae018>] (tsg_ioctl+0x3e4/0x954)
```

Comment: provide a full stack trace and a code snippet (with context) of how you are invoking arm_dma_alloc. Most likely, the reason is that you are calling sleep capable function (arm_dma_alloc) from atomic context, where sleep is forbidden. Probably you making this allocation under spin_lock

Comment: You're right, I called with a spinlock held. But is this the only reason such a timeout can occur?

Comment: Yes, that is the reason. As you see it is a schedule bug . See my answer for more details also may this will be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537252/how-to-solve-bug-scheduling-while-atomic-swapper-0x00000103-0-cpu0-in-ts?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, the reason is that you are calling sleep capable function (`arm_dma_alloc`) from atomic context, where sleep is forbidden. Probably you making this allocation under `spin_lock`.
The `spin_lock` calls [preempt_disable](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/locking/spinlock.c#L355), what means there is no rescheduling possible. That is how `spin_lock` works. Anyhow, if you will call sleeping primitive inside `spin_lock / spin_unlock` and reschedule will happen, the kernel scheduler subsystem will warn you, that you have rescheduled in atomic context (this is what you are seeing in this message).