# Waiting in Linux Kernel Module(Driver) Critical Section for user-space input

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver

I'm new to kernel programming and I was making changes in a Linux Driver. I want to block/wait in a Critical Section for user input(The communication between the Driver and the user-space Application work). The Problem is that when I used wait_event_timeout() the System is being crashed and I am getting 
`BUG: scheduling while atomic: swapper`. 
 Is anybody have any idea how to solve this problem and can give me some advice where to start?

Comment: You can't wait for user input in a critical section. This is a BUG. How do you want to get the "user input"? How do you enter a critical section? Critical sections are for atomic operations only, not for I/O

Comment: I get the user input through a netlink socket. I wrote a callback function for receiving msgs in the drv_init file not in a critical section. I want to block/wait in the critical section until the callback function has been called.

Comment: Yeah - your design is borked:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained [in other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537252/how-to-solve-bug-scheduling-while-atomic-swapper-0x00000103-0-cpu0-in-ts), you are calling wait_event_timeout in a context when you already have some lock acquired (inside a critical section). In this point your process can potentially deadlock with other processes and the scheduler complains about it. Please, review the point where you are calling wait_event_timeout and check if the I/O is performed in the correct place and if you have unlocked all synchronization primitives before sending your process to sleep.